# English idiom or a phrasal verb I could use to express that something can't be counted with money?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, grammaticality, idioms

Is there an English idiom or a phrasal verb I could use to express that something can't be counted with money ?

For example when something is so risky or important that it can't be counted with money.

For context: "The risk is very high however many women agree to be surrogate mothers.They are well-paid but I think pregnancy and delivery can't be counted with money."

I've added **the** before **pregnancy** and **delivery** but removed it because I think that articles are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the word “invaluable”, which literally means you can’t value something.

A common idiom people use is to say you “can’t put a price on” something. For example:

> Though surrogate mothers are well paid, you really **can’t put a price on** the risks involved in pregnancy and delivery.

Comment: Can I say "No matter how much a surrogate mother  charges, it won't be enough to pay in full"?

Comment: It wouldn’t be particularly idiomatic, as “pay in full” is very much a financial term, and doesn’t really lend itself to what you’re trying to express.

Comment: Would you please suggest a similar expression instad of "pay in full"?

Comment: I would suggest something like, “... enough to truly compensate her [for the risks she’s taking].”

Comment: Or "No matter how much a surrogate mother charges, she can never truly be repaid."

Answer (score 1):

"The risk is very high however many women agree to be surrogate mothers.They are well-paid but I think pregnancy and delivery can't be counted with money."

I propose 'should not be equated with the money'.  Also, 'pay well' as 'pregnancy and delivery' is the antecedent of the pronoun 'they'.  Lastly, I add some punctuation signs.

My suggestion is as follows:

"The risk is very high; however, many women agree to be surrogate mothers.  They pay well but I think pregnancy and delivery should not be equated with the money."